# Summing items within a Tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is a data structure of List of tuples, ot type List[(String, String, Int)]

```
   val data3 = (List( ("id1" , "a", 1), ("id1" , "a", 1), ("id1" , "a", 1) , ("id2" , "a", 1)) )
                                                  //> data3  : List[(String, String, Int)] = List((id1,a,1), (id1,a,1), (id1,a,1),
                                                  //|  (id2,a,1))
```

I'm attempting to count the occurences of each Int value associated with each id. So above data structure should be converted to `List((id1,a,3) , (id2,a,1))`

This is what I have come up with but I'm unsure how to group similar items within a Tuple :

```
data3.map( { case (id,name,num) => (id , name , num + 1)})
                                              //> res0: List[(String, String, Int)] = List((id1,a,2), (id1,a,2), (id1,a,2), (i
                                              //| d2,a,2))
```

In practice data3 is of type spark obj RDD , I'm using a List in this example for testing but same solution should be compatible with an RDD . I'm using a List for local testing purposes.

Update : based on following code provided by maasg :

```
val byKey = rdd.map({case (id1,id2,v) => (id1,id2)->v})
val byKeyGrouped = byKey.groupByKey
val result = byKeyGrouped.map{case ((id1,id2),values) => (id1,id2,values.sum)}
```

I needed to amend slightly to get into format I expect which is of type

```
.RDD[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])]
which corresponds to .RDD[(id, Seq[(name, count-of-names)])]
```

:

```
val byKey = rdd.map({case (id1,id2,v) => (id1,id2)->v})
val byKeyGrouped = byKey.groupByKey
val result = byKeyGrouped.map{case ((id1,id2),values) => ((id1),(id2,values.sum))}
val counted = result.groupedByKey
```

Comment: As you tag this with #Spark, is this within an RDD ?

Comment: @maasg please see question update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark, you would do something like this:  (using Spark Shell to illustrate)

```
val l = List( ("id1" , "a", 1), ("id1" , "a", 1), ("id1" , "a", 1) , ("id2" , "a", 1))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
val grouped = rdd.groupBy{case (id1,id2,v) => (id1,id2)}
val result = grouped.map{case ((id1,id2),values) => (id1,id2,value.foldLeft(0){case (cumm, tuple) => cumm + tuple._3})}
```

Another option would be to map the rdd into a `PairRDD` and use `groupByKey`:

```
val byKey = rdd.map({case (id1,id2,v) => (id1,id2)->v})
val byKeyGrouped = byKey.groupByKey
val result = byKeyGrouped.map{case ((id1,id2),values) => (id1,id2,values.sum)}
```

Option 2 is a slightly better option when handling large sets as it does not replicate the id's in the cummulated value.

Comment: thanks, I needed to amend your solution in order to get into format I'm expecting, please see question update. Do you think this is a good solution ?

Comment: @blue-sky  It looks good to me. That's different from your original example, though.  Are you using Spark-shell to try out things? It's very handy to explore these kind of transformations before running them 'on the large'

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work when I use scala-ide:

```
data3
  .groupBy(tupl => (tupl._1, tupl._2))
  .mapValues(v =>(v.head._1,v.head._2, v.map(_._3).sum))
  .values.toList
```

And the result is the same as required by the question

> res0: List[(String, String, Int)] = List((id1,a,3), (id2,a,1))

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `List.groupBy`.

You can use the id as the key, and then use the length of your values in the map (ie all the items sharing the same id) to know the count.

Answer (score 1):

@vptheron has the right idea.
As can be seen in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

> def groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): Map[K, List[A]]
>
> Partitions this list into a map of lists according to some discriminator function.
>
> Note: this method is not re-implemented by views. This means when applied to a view it will >always force the view and return a new list.
>
> **K** the type of keys returned by the discriminator function.
>   **f** the discriminator function.
>   **returns**
>      A map from keys to lists such that the following invariant holds:
>      (xs partition f)(k) = xs filter (x => f(x) == k)
>      That is, every key k is bound to a list of those elements x for which f(x) equals k.

So something like the below function, when used with `groupBy` will give you a list with keys being the ids.
(Sorry, I don't have access to an Scala compiler, so I can't test)

```
def f(tupule: A) :String = {
  return tupule._1
}
```

Then you will have to iterate through the `List` for each `id` in the `Map` and sum up the number of integer occurrences. That is straightforward, but if you still need help, ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the most readable, efficient and scalable

```
data.map {
  case (key1, key2, value) => ((key1, key2), value)
}
.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

which will give a `RDD[(String, String, Int)]`.  By using `reduceByKey` it means the summation will paralellize, i.e. for very large groups it will be distributed and summation will happen *on the map side*.  Think about the case where there are only 10 groups but billions of records, using `.sum` won't scale as it will only be able to distribute to 10 cores.

A few more notes about the other answers:

Using `head` here is unnecessary: `.mapValues(v =>(v.head._1,v.head._2, v.map(_._3).sum))` can just use `.mapValues(v =>(v_1, v._2, v.map(_._3).sum))`

Using a `foldLeft` here is really horrible when the above shows `.map(_._3).sum` will do: `val result = grouped.map{case ((id1,id2),values) => (id1,id2,value.foldLeft(0){case (cumm, tuple) => cumm + tuple._3})}`